# Convert MPEG to VOB without reencoding

Tags: vob, mpg, dvdauthor

I have mpg video with lossless audio. I would like authorize dvd without reencoding, for example, with dvdstyler: [VOB files will normally neither be reencoded nor be remultiplexed](https://sourceforge.net/p/dvdstyler/wiki/FAQVob/) in case.

So I have choice loose lossless audio (not supported) with reencode or make vob files and use them without reencoding.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg [-codec copy] output.vob
```

not supported lossless audio with mpg/vob files too.

How make vob files from mpg without reencoding?

PS

In addition I would like store video clips in separated vob files.

workout:

I've just rename mpg to vob and DVDstyler accept lpcm

Answer (score 1):

From **MPEG-2** spec I can't see support of lossless audio options:

- MFAudioFormat_PCM: Number of channels × 2.
- MFAudioFormat_Float: Number of channels × 4.

```bsh
ffmpeg -i input.avi -target pal-dvd output.vob
```

man page from *ffmpeg*

```
-target type (output)
           Specify target file type ("vcd", "svcd", "dvd", "dv", "dv50"). type may be prefixed with "pal-", "ntsc-" or "film-" to use the corresponding standard. All the format options (bitrate, codecs, buffer sizes) are then set
           automatically. You can just type:

                   ffmpeg -i myfile.avi -target vcd /tmp/vcd.mpg

           Nevertheless you can specify additional options as long as you know they do not conflict with the standard, as in:

                   ffmpeg -i myfile.avi -target vcd -bf 2 /tmp/vcd.mpg
```